# Set array elements based on current time

Tags: time, swiftui

I currently have the code below:

```
var arrayEX = ["8:00 - 11:00", "11:00 - 2:00", "2:00 - 5:00"]
@State var selectedtime = ""



Picker("Start time", selection: $selectedtime) {
    ForEach(arrayEX, id: \.self) {
        Text($0)
        }
    }
    .padding()
    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
```

My question is; How can I not show the 1st element of the array after 8:00am, the 2nd element after 11:00am, and the 3rd element after 2:00pm with a message saying there are no times left today?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you look at the Date/TIme comparisons methods with Calendar?

Comment: I was trying to think of a way to use an if statement such as `if time is past 8:00 { don't show the first element` but I don't know where to put it, or how to make it more efficient than tons of if statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this approach, where the start times are converted to minutes and then filtered according to the current time.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // -- here, note 24h clock and consistent pattern `hh:mm`
    var arrayEX = ["08:00 - 11:00", "11:00 - 14:00", "14:00 - 17:00"]
    @State var selectedtime = ""
    @State var timesLeft: [String] = [] // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Start time", selection: $selectedtime) {
            ForEach(timesLeft, id: \.self) {  // <-- here timesLeft
                Text($0)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        .onAppear {

            let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: .now)
            let minute = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: .now)
            let minutesNow = (Int(hour)*60) + Int(minute) // <-- minutes since the start of day
            
            // convert start times to minutes
            let startTimes: [Int] = arrayEX.map{
                let h = String($0.prefix(2))
                let m = String($0.dropFirst(3).prefix(2))
                return ((Int(h) ?? 0) * 60) + (Int(m) ?? 0)
            }

            // find the index in arrayEX where we are past the time
            if let ndx = startTimes.firstIndex(where: { $0 > minutesNow }) {
                timesLeft = Array(arrayEX.suffix(from: ndx))
            } else {
                timesLeft = ["no times left today"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```